# Выборка записей из двух таблиц с условием "месяц назад"

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `fclients, yclients` и у них совершенно разные поля и нету никаких связей между ними и не должны быть. Но нужно одновременно выбрать из из двух таблиц все записи которые созданы месяц назад. Дата создания записей храниится в поле `last_request`. Пытаюсь создать такие запросы

```
select a.client_id, a.fio,a.adress, a.rout a.last_request, b.yclient_id, b.orgname, b.yphone, b.yadress, b.yroute from fclients a, yclients b where a.last_request = < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) OR b.last_request = < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
```

Выдает ошибку

> ## 1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе

и советует изучать документацию.

И пытаюсь делать такой запрос

```
select * from fclients, yclients where fclients.last_request < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) OR yclients.last_request < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
```

Второй запрос в отличие от предыдущего работает, но выдает результаты "бок о бок" т е , записи из двух таблиц находятся рядом а не в отдельной строке...

ПОсоветуйте правильный запрос, друзья

Comment: сделать два запроса, будут в разных строках

Comment: спасибо за ответ, а можете чуть чуть по подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: что именно подробнее, я просто не понял, почему вы хотите использовать один запрос, а данные получить раздельно. просто сначала достаньте данные из одной таблицы, потом из другой - другим запросом.

Comment: дело в том что мне надо их "запихнуть" в одну HTML таблицу

Comment: если не вперемешку, то сначала выведете данные первого запроса, потом второго, потом закроете таблицу

Comment: А если надо по времени, делайте union и потом сортируйте по времени. тогда получите один массив

Comment: думал такое никто не использует, оказывается нет ...ошибался. А других способов никаких видать ? \

Comment: Про массив, не совсем понял (

Comment: У вас одинаковый набор полей в обеих таблицах?

Comment: нет не одинаковые, по этому и сомневался насчет union

Comment: а как вы тогда их хотите в один результирующий набор, но в разные строки? и как вы их потом в одном цикле в таблицу будете записывать?

Comment: По этому я и обратился сюда за советом )

Comment: так вы определитесь что вы хотите в результате. Можно и за одно и за второе побороться, толь данных мало

Comment: мне бы вывести результаты в одной таблице и не рядом т е результат из каждой таблицы в отдельной строке .вот И все это одним запросом желательно

Comment: тогда простое решение - два последовательных запроса.

Comment: спасибо. тогда таки сделаю